# Calculate indefinite integral $\int \frac{dx}{({x^2-2x+5})^{3/2}} $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have this indefinite integral
$$I=\int \frac{dx}{({x^2-2x+5})^{3/2}} $$
I tried to complete the square and substitute $ u = x-1 $

$$I=\int \frac{du}{8(\frac{u^2}{4}+1)^{{3/2}}} = \frac{1}{8}\int \frac{du}{(\frac{u^2}{4}+1)^{{3/2}}}$$

Now, I am stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: Since the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ of $a+bx+cx^2$ is non-zero, you will be sure to find a primitive in the form $(Ax+B)/(a+bx+cx^2)^{1/2}$. Thus, one way is to differentiate and compare... (I leave this as a comment, since I don't truly support remembering things like this. Nevertheless, someone might find it useful.)

Answer (score 3):

Hint...substitute $x=1+2\tan\theta$

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Integration by substitution

Comment: i dont see the connection between the $tan$ and the equation.

Comment: Make the sub and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably get this far on your own: for any real number $a$,

$$\begin{align}
I{\left(a\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{a}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(x^2-2x+5\right)^{3/2}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{a}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left[\left(x-1\right)^2+4\right]^{3/2}}\\
&=\int_{-1}^{a-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\left(y^2+4\right)^{3/2}};~~~\small{\left[x-1=y\right]}\\
&=\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac{a-1}{2}}\frac{2}{\left[4\left(t^2+1\right)\right]^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{\left[y=2t\right]}\\
&=\frac14\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac{a-1}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\left(t^2+1\right)^{3/2}};~~~\small{\left[y=2t\right]}.\\
\end{align}$$

Next, use the product rule and chain rule to find the following derivative:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\right]
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}+t\,\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}-\frac{t^{2}}{\left(t^2+1\right)^{3/2}}\\
&=\frac{\left(t^2+1\right)}{\left(t^2+1\right)^{3/2}}-\frac{t^{2}}{\left(t^2+1\right)^{3/2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\left(t^2+1\right)^{3/2}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
I{\left(a\right)}
&=\frac14\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac{a-1}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\left(t^2+1\right)^{3/2}}\\
&=\frac14\left[\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\right]_{-\frac12}^{\frac{a-1}{2}}\\
&=\frac14\left[\frac{\left(\frac{a-1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a-1}{2}\right)^2+1}}-\frac{\left(-\frac12\right)}{\sqrt{\left(-\frac12\right)^2+1}}\right]\\
&=\frac14\left[\frac{\left(a-1\right)}{\sqrt{\left(a-1\right)^2+2^{2}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2^{2}}}\right]\\
&=\frac{\left(a-1\right)}{4\sqrt{\left(a-1\right)^2+4}}+\frac{1}{4\sqrt{5}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Once you've reached the final answer, it's easy to verify that it's correct by checking the derivative

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\left(x-1\right)}{4\sqrt{x^2-2x+5}}\right]=\frac{1}{\left(x^{2}-2x+5\right)^{3/2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y= \sqrt {x^2-2x+5}$. Then, $ydy=(x-1)dx$ and

\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{({x^2-2x+5})^{3/2}}&= \int \frac{dx}{y^3}
=\int \frac{[y^2-(x-1)^2]dx}{4y^3}\\
&=\frac14\int\left(\frac{dx}y-\frac{(x-1)dy}{y^2}\right)\\
&=\frac14\int d\left(\frac{x-1}{y}\right)=\frac{x-1}{4y}+C
\end{align}